# PySpark read CSV file with custom record separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to use custom record delimiters while reading a csv file in pyspark. In my file records are separated by `**` instead of newline. Is there any way of using this custom line/record separator when reading the csv into a PySpark dataframe?

Comment: did you try `("delimiter", "**")`

Comment: that wont work as delimiter works as a column identifier

Comment: Can you provide sample data of `5` rows

Comment: Same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700724/read-a-file-in-pyspark-with-custom-column-and-record-delmiter. Please se my asnwer

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as here [Read a file in pyspark with custom column and record delmiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700724/read-a-file-in-pyspark-with-custom-column-and-record-delmiter)

I would read it as a pure text file into a rdd and then split on the character that is your line break. Afterwards convert it to a dataframe
Like this

```
rdd1= (sc
       .textFile("/jupyter/nfs/test.txt")
       .flatMap(lambda line: line.split("**"))
       .map(lambda x: x.split(";"))
      )
df1=rdd1.toDF(["a","b","c"])
df1.show()

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
| a1| b1| c1|
| a2| b2| c2|
| a3| b2| c3|
+---+---+---+
```

or if like this

```
rdd2= (sc
       .textFile("/jupyter/nfs/test.txt")
       .flatMap(lambda line: line.split("**"))
       .map(lambda x: [x])
      )
df2=(rdd2
     .toDF(["abc"])
     .withColumn("a",f.split(f.col("abc"),";")[0])
     .withColumn("b",f.split(f.col("abc"),";")[1])
     .withColumn("c",f.split(f.col("abc"),";")[2])
     .drop("abc")
    )
df2.show()

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
| a1| b1| c1|
| a2| b2| c2|
| a3| b2| c3|
+---+---+---+
```

where the test.txt looks like

```
a1;b1;c1**a2;b2;c2**a3;b2;c3
```