# Read a file in pyspark with custom column and record delmiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to use custom record delimiters while reading a csv file in pyspark. In my file records are separated by ** instead of newline. Is there any way of using this custom line/record separator when reading the csv into a PySpark dataframe? Also my column seperators are ';' The code below gets the columns correctly but it counts as only one row

```
from pyspark import SparkContext 
sc =  SparkSession.builder.appName('temp').getOrCreate()
df = sc.read.format('csv').option("header", "false").option("delimiter", ';').option("inferSchema", "true").load("some-file-on-s3")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would read it as a pure text file into a rdd and then split on the character that is your line break. Afterwards convert it to a dataframe
Like this

```
rdd1= (sc
       .textFile("/jupyter/nfs/test.txt")
       .flatMap(lambda line: line.split("**"))
       .map(lambda x: x.split(";"))
      )
df1=rdd1.toDF(["a","b","c"])
df1.show()

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
| a1| b1| c1|
| a2| b2| c2|
| a3| b2| c3|
+---+---+---+
```

or if like this

```
rdd2= (sc
       .textFile("/jupyter/nfs/test.txt")
       .flatMap(lambda line: line.split("**"))
       .map(lambda x: [x])
      )
df2=(rdd2
     .toDF(["abc"])
     .withColumn("a",f.split(f.col("abc"),";")[0])
     .withColumn("b",f.split(f.col("abc"),";")[1])
     .withColumn("c",f.split(f.col("abc"),";")[2])
     .drop("abc")
    )
df2.show()

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
| a1| b1| c1|
| a2| b2| c2|
| a3| b2| c3|
+---+---+---+
```

where the test.txt looks like

```
a1;b1;c1**a2;b2;c2**a3;b2;c3
```

Comment: this is a  greater then 1TB file size, will this load all data in the memory at once. How could I use rdd and parallelize this load across my cluster

Comment: Spark follows the paradigm of lazy loading. As long as you  apply transformations  no data will be loaded. The data will be loaded in memory as soon as you call an action like show(), count(), collect() or write().  Spark running on a cluster takes care itself to distribute and compute everything across the cluster. Thats what Spark is all about. The memory spark needs depends on the transformation you apply. As all the data are split in junks, Spark typically does not need the same memory as the file you want process (execept you cache it)

Comment: Also Spark will spill data on disk before it runs out of memory. Memory issues are occuring if you cache the rdd/df not smart or apply expensiv operations like loops or large joins (e.g. cross join)

Comment: thanks , quite helpful . is it possible to use regexp in the above as columns might be split by onr or more ';' and the extra ';' just need to be ignored

Comment: yes, you can use every python function as a lambda function as far as I used it so far. To see it more exactly comment out each step and show to the resulting rdd with rdd.take(4) or rdd.collect(). rdd only knows rows. So first step is to get rows and than to format the rows in such a way that you can later on create a dataframe out of it. If you need a dataframe. You can of course also do everything in rdd rows and at the end write it out again row wise